# Angular 2 routes: resolve not called for children

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Using:

```
"@angular/core": "2.2.2",
"@angular/router": "3.2.2",
```

Routes look like:

```
export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', resolve: { profile: PrefetchProfileService },
    children: [
      {path: '', component: Pages.LandingComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'pl', component: PersonalLoanComponent},
      {path: 'login', component: Pages.LoginComponent, canActivate: [ExistingSessionGuard]},
      {path: 'register', component: Pages.RegisterComponent, canActivate: [ExistingSessionGuard]},
      {path: 'home', component: Pages.HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    ]
  }
];
```

The issue is that resolve is not triggering for any direct navigation to a child path. Ex: if user navigates directly to /login, PrefetchProfileService is not called. If user navigates to /, then goes to /login, everything is fine. How do I deal with this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add resolve in each child route you want to use PrefetchProfileService.

```
path: '', resolve: { profile: PrefetchProfileService },
        children: [
          {path: '', component: Pages.LandingComponent,resolve: { profile: PrefetchProfileService } ,pathMatch: 'full'},
          {path: 'pl', resolve: { profile: PrefetchProfileService },component: PersonalLoanComponent},
          {path: 'login', resolve: { profile: PrefetchProfileService },component: Pages.LoginComponent, canActivate: [ExistingSessionGuard]},
          {path: 'register', resolve: { profile: PrefetchProfileService },component: Pages.RegisterComponent, canActivate: [ExistingSessionGuard]},
          {path: 'home',resolve: { profile: PrefetchProfileService } ,component: Pages.HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}

,
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work but is hugely annoying for lots of routes.  It also goes against how guards work (applied in parallel, starting from the topmost parent). I ended up doing my prefetch with the guard instead :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use runGuardsAndResolvers: "always" at your parent route