# Unable to trigger 'resolve' or 'guard' on child routes of a parameterised route path in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

This may seem like a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107068/angular-2-routes-resolve-not-called-for-children) but I couldn't find a solution for this (when url is parameterised). I also found a related [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12942), whose status is fixed. But that doesn't serve my purpose.

I am using:

```
"@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
"@angular/router": "^3.3.1",


{ path : 'Account/Registration/:step', component: RegistrationComponent, pathMatch: "prefix",
    children : [
        { path: "Get-Otp", component: RegistrationComponent, resolve:{ actionData : ActionResolve}},
    ]
}
```

The resolve doesn't get called, even a "canActivate" or a "canActivateChild" guard won't get called. Can you please point me in the right direction, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

recently i was able to resolve data ..hope this helps

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^3.6.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.2",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: HomeComponent,
        resolve: {
            auth: AuthResolverService
        }
    }
];



import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Resolve, Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthResolverService implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private router: Router) {
    console.log('constructor: AuthResolverService');
    this.af.auth.subscribe(
      user => {
        console.log('constructor: AuthResolverService --> ', user);
      },
      error => console.trace(error)
    );
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    console.log('AuthResolverService');
    return this.af.auth.first();
  }

}
```